Complex Conjugation of Function with branch cut behaves unexpectedly to me
I stumbled upon the following observation of unintuitive behaviour of complex conjugation of a function with a branch cut and wanted to ask if I make any mistakes or whether my conclusion is correct?
I want to understand the behaviour of the square root function under complex conjugation $x \mapsto x^*$. In particular I choose the following two versions
define $1)\ (e^{i\phi})^{1/2} = e^{i \phi/2}, \phi \in (-\pi,\pi)$ and $2)\ (e^{i\phi})^{1/2} = e^{i \phi/2}, \phi \in (0,2\pi)$
Now let $\phi \in (0, \pi/2)$ be in the first quadrant and look at $x = e^{i\phi}$
Under 1) I find
$(x^*)^{1/2} = (e^{-i\phi})^{1/2} = e^{-i\phi/2} = (e^{i \phi/2})^* =(x^{1/2})^*$ So first conjugating and taking the square root give me the same value.
However for 2) I see $ (x^*)^{1/2} = (e^{i (2 \pi-\phi)})^{1/2} = e^{i\pi} e^{-i\phi/2}= - (x^{1/2})^{*}$. So it seems to me that the behaviour of the square root function under complex conjugation depends on the location of the branch cut. I just never saw this effect before and was wondering if I am doing something wrong?

That' the conundrum of the halving of angles on the unit circle. To act nathematically sound use the unit circle with its inifinite cover by $(-\infty, \infty)\mod (2\pi, \phi_0) $ with free cut at $\phi_0$. Very smart people use $\mod (4 \pi)$, such that within two rounds the map ist smooth. In representation theory of the rotation group the basic rotations are parametrized by $\cos \phi/2, \sin \phi/2$   with a 2-component spinor, such that rotations by $4\pi$ are the identity,while rotations by $2 \pi$ yield a sign change.

I understand your comment as saying that the two branch cuts amount to different choices of $\phi_0$, correct? However I do not understand how this changes anything wrt complex conjugation..

(i) In the hope of complementing Paul's (+1) answer, the diagrams in my answer here suggest geometric intuition: Depending where we put the branch cut, the square root is or isn't reflection-symmetric across the real axis. (ii) With all kindness, don't describe yourself or your questions as stupid. The reasons are lengthy to detail in a comment, but in my view doing so is harmful, to others as well as to you, more so than it might appear. :)


Thank you for the comment and 2) I have removed the word "stupid" from my question.


You are right. Let us look at the complex sqare root branches defined on sliced planes.
Given $w \in S^1 = \{ z \in \mathbb C \mid \lvert z \rvert = 1\}$, we define the sliced plane
$$\mathbb C_w = \mathbb C \setminus R_w$$
where $R_w = \{tw \mid t \in [0,\infty)\}$. On each $\mathbb C_w$ there are two continuous square root functions
$$s_\pm : \mathbb C_w \to \mathbb C .$$
This means that $s_\pm(z)^2 = z$ for all $z \in \mathbb C_w$. They are related by $s_- = -s_+$. Note that they are even holomorphic.
Let $w = e^{i\Omega}$ with $\Omega \in \mathbb R$. Note that $\Omega$ is not unique (it is determined only up to a summand $2k\pi$ with $k \in \mathbb Z$).
Then each $z \in \mathbb C_w$ can uniquely written in the form
$$z = re^{i\phi} \text{ with } r \in (0,\infty) \text{ and } \phi \in (\Omega,\Omega + 2\pi) $$
and we can define
$$s_\Omega : \mathbb C_w \to  \mathbb C, s_\Omega(z) = \sqrt r e^{i\phi/2}.$$
This is continuous square root function; $-s_\Omega$ is the other one. You can easily check that $-s_\Omega = s_{\Omega + 2\pi}$.
$s_\Omega$ being compatible with complex conjugation means that
$$s_\Omega(z^*) = s_\Omega(z)^* \tag{1}$$
Clearly $s_\Omega$ is compatible with complex conjugation iff $-s_\Omega$ is.
If $w \notin \{+1,-1\}$, then $(1)$ cannot be satisfied for all $z \in \mathbb C_w$ since $(\mathbb C_w)^* = \mathbb C_{w^*} \ne \mathbb C_w$. In fact, $(1)$ can at best be satisfied for $z \in \mathbb C_w \cap \mathbb C_{w^*}$. We shall not study this case, but restrict to $w = \pm 1$.
For $w=1$ one usually takes $\Omega = 0$. As you have shown, one has
$$s_0(z^*) = - s_0(z)^* .$$
Any other choice of $\Omega$ produces the same phenomenon. Thus there is no branch of the square root on $\mathbb C_1 = \mathbb C \setminus [0,\infty)$ which is compatible with complex conjugation.
For $w=-1$ one usually takes $\Omega = -\pi$. As you have shown, one has
$$s_{-\pi}(z^*) =  s_{-\pi}(z)^* .$$
The same is true for any other choice of $\Omega$. Anyway, the principal  branch of the square root on $\mathbb C_{-1} = \mathbb C \setminus (-\infty,0]$ is is compatible with complex conjugation.
